# xhtml2pdf not converting css properly django

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf, pisa

hey guys so i have been using this library for a while now and i just encounter this error that by using this library its not converting my css of my html properly to pdf, i used this library to generate voucher internet for my client, does anybody now how can i fix this? thanks, here's my code

voucher.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        
        * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .row {
        display: flex;
        margin-left:-5px;
        margin-right:-5px;
        }

        .column {
        flex: 50%;
        padding: 5px;
        }

        table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;

        }

        th, td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    @page {
        size: letter landscape;
        margin: 2cm;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
        {% for data in akun %}
            <div class="column">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Voucher Internet 1 Hari</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>{{akun.username}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>{{akun.password}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Harga</td>
                        <td>{{akun.harga}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">Mikadmin.net</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

view.py

```
    def voucher_profile(request):
        mikrotik_session = request.session.get("mikadmin")
        template = get_template('voucher.html')
        host     = mikrotik_session.get("host")
        username = mikrotik_session.get("username")
        password = mikrotik_session.get("password")
        con  = routeros_api.RouterOsApiPool(host=host,username=username,password=password,plaintext_login=True)
        api  = con.get_api()
        content = api.get_resource('ip/hotspot/user/profile')
        content_user = api.get_resource('ip/hotspot/user')
        username_paket_profile = request.POST['name-profile']
        valid = request.POST['valid']
        limit_bandwidth = request.POST['rate-limit']
        harga_voucher = request.POST['harga-voucher']
        count_generate = request.POST['count_generate']
        akun = []
        content.add(
            name=username_paket_profile,
            shared_users="1",
            rate_limit=limit_bandwidth,
            status_autorefresh="1m",
            transparent_proxy="yes",
            on_login="""{
            :local pengguna $user;
            :local date [/system clock get date];
            :local time [/system clock get time];
            :log warning "$pengguna telah login pada jam $time";
            :if ([/ip hotspot user find name=$pengguna limit-uptime=%s]="") do={
            /ip hotspot user set [find name=$pengguna] limit-uptime=%s
            /ip hotspot active remove [find user=$pengguna]
            };
            :if ([/system schedule find name=$pengguna]="") do={
            /system schedule add name=$pengguna interval=%s on-event="/ip hotspot user remove [find name=$pengguna]\r\n/ip hotspot active remove [find user=$pengguna]\r\n/system schedule remove [find name=$pengguna]"
            }
            }""" % (valid, valid, valid))

        for data in range(int(count_generate)):
            generate_name = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(6))
            generate_password = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(6))
            content_user.add(name=generate_name,password=generate_password,profile=username_paket_profile)
            ctx = {"username":generate_name,"password":generate_password,"harga":harga_voucher}
            akun.append(ctx)

        context = {"akun":akun}
        html  = template.render(context)
        nama_file = 'voucher paket generate.pdf'
        file = open(nama_file, "w+b")
        pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file,
                encoding='utf-8')

        file.seek(0)
        pdf = file.read()
        file.close()            
        return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 4):

xhmtl2pdf supports only limited number of css properties as described in the [docs page](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#supported-css-properties):

```
background-color
border-bottom-color, border-bottom-style, border-bottom-width
border-left-color, border-left-style, border-left-width
border-right-color, border-right-style, border-right-width
border-top-color, border-top-style, border-top-width
colordisplay
font-family, font-size, font-style, font-weight
height
line-height, list-style-type
margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top
padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, padding-top
page-break-after, page-break-before
size
text-align, text-decoration, text-indent
vertical-align
white-space
width
zoom
```

And adds few of its own for defining its own styling:

```
-pdf-frame-border
-pdf-frame-break
-pdf-frame-content
-pdf-keep-with-next
-pdf-next-page
-pdf-outline
-pdf-outline-level
-pdf-outline-open
-pdf-page-break
```

Namely it does not accept `flex`, `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` from your code.

Use its [pages and frames to define layout](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_html.html#defining-page-layouts) instead of flex columns.

Also doc says that it has some default styling for the page, which you may dump, edit or replace like described [here](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-special-properties):

```
# dump
$ xhtml2pdf --css-dump > xhtml2pdf-default.css
```

```
# replace
$ xhtml2pdf --css=xhtml2pdf-default.css test.html
```

Comment: oh i just knew that, but how i can achieve to make my table side to side when converting it to pdf using xhtml2pdf? because the way i achieve that in my css by using flex-box, i try using the page@ but it seems dosent do anything at all can you give me some help or tips or maybe library that i can used to do this? thanks

Comment: Probably you need to make a table with multiple tds in each tr. If your design does not strictly require multiple tables - display a single table with multiple tds in each row.

Also you may render page in browser and use js to download a pdf from it: https://www.codexworld.com/convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-jspdf/